# Real-time HTML source editing in Chrome dev tools "Elements" view?

Tags: html, browser, google-chrome-devtools, editing, opera-dragonfly

My problem / backstory: I'm still using Opera 12 (Presto-based) with it's Dragonfly dev tools for quick CSS and HTML editing.

Obviously, other browsers are more modern and generally faster, but Dragonfly is the only in-browser tool that allows me to edit any HTML element's source in real time.

I can just double click on any element in the dev tools DOM view (instead of clunky right-clicking -> "Edit as HTML" in Chrome), and then all changes are reflected instantly in real time in the main browser window.

In Chrome and other browsers I've tried, this workflow is a pain, because changes are not updated in real time, but only after closing the HTML editor with Ctrl+Enter (or similar).

**Long story short:**
Is there any modern browser that allows real-time editing of HTML source, like Dragonfly in Opera 12 does? Maybe even with the help of extensions?

Comment: you can double click and edit the element or properties in chrome.

Comment: Yeah but only the element (tag name) itself and the attributes, not the HTML content including all children of the element. Have to use right-click -> "Edit as HTML" for that.

Answer (score 1):

You can try Firebug for Firefox http://getfirebug.com/. It has live html editor in its HTML view. There is also Firebug Lite if you prefer Chrome editor https://getfirebug.com/firebuglite. Also, in the latests versions of Chrome, its developer tools allow you to change element type and its attributes by double clicking on it.

Comment: I'll look into Firebug, thanks. Have used it in the past, but that's quite some time ago... so probably, things have changed since then :)

Concerning the double-click edit: That works for the tag name and attributes, but not for the HTML content. So it is (most often) not enough for my kind of usage.

Comment: Hmm, well.... Firebug is nice but still doesn't justify the change from Dragonfly for me... Dragonfly is still faster (Firebug has a noticable delay while editing, approx. 1 second). Besides that, I simply prefer the general UI of Dragonfly, and also the Chrome dev tools for that matter (even if they lack real-time editing).

Comment: Anyway, thanks for your answer. I'll still keep looking, though :)